# Does a Pokemon's Attack stat affect the Pokemon's move damage?

Tags: pokemon-quest

Pokemon moves have their own move power to determine their damage output. But does the Pokemon's Attack stat affect the damage dealt from moves, or does it only affect normal damage without affecting moves i.e. only affect when you tell the Pokemon to attack without issuing moves.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The Attack stat affects the moves in addition to the non-move normal attacks. If you use a move from a low level Pokemon, and then use the same move from a much higher level Pokemon, you will notice a substantial difference in their damage output.

It is important that the moves deal more damage with a greater Attack stat, since with a set damage output, otherwise the move would deal too much damage when Pokemon are at low levels, too little damage when Pokemon are at high levels, or both (in a similar vein to the move Dragon Rage in the mainstream Pokemon games which always deals 40 damage).